# Problema con los driver de hp para wifi de linux

Tags: linux

Acabo de instalar linux mint en mi notebook hp y no me reconoce los driver del wifi por ser privativo, alguien conoce alguna version free compatible?

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: La mayoria de drivers no soportan Linux de por si, la unica forma de hacer que funciones es buscar la version de tu hardware en google y buscar si existe algun paquete/parche para descargar.

Comment: Primero que todo, no es una pregunta de programación como tal. Aun así debes ver si tu tarjeta es `Nvidia` o `Intel`, son los mas comunes, usa este comando:  `sudo lspci -nn | grep Wireless` para que te de una idea de donde descargar el controlador